# Jquery add row and set input values after add

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a row to a table with input fields and set the input fields values at the same time. Below is my code and I receive an error:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #ItemName[]

Can any one help identify what I am doing incorrectly?

Any help is appreciated.

```html
$('#addItem').click(function() {
$('#itemData tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td align="left"><input id="ItemName[]" name="ItemName[]" type="hidden" value="">cellAAA</td><td align="left"><input id="ItemNombre[]" name="ItemNombre[]" type="hidden" value="">cellBBB</td><td>edit / delete</td></tr>');
 var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent()) - 1;
 $("#itemData td:contains('cellAAA')").html($("#itemName").val());
 $("#itemData td:contains('cellBBB')").html($("#itemNombre").val());
 $("#ItemName[]")[row].val($("#itemName").val());
 $("#ItemNombre[]")[row].val($("#itemNombre").val());
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty certain that you need to escape the [] characters with \\ so every time you use a bracket char precede it with a \\ when using a jQuery selector.  It's worth noting that javascript will do the same thing without the escaping.

So...
$("#ItemNombre\\[\\]")[row].val($("#itemNombre").val());

Comment: That looked hopeful but now I am receiving the following error: TypeError: $(...)[row] is undefined
 $("#ItemName\\[\\]")[row].val($("#itemName").val());

Comment: This system edited out the extra backslash. This is the actual code $("#ItemName\\\[\\\]")[row].val($("#itemName").val());

Answer (score 0):

joshin855 our suggestion fixed the major issue I was having, but removing

```html
 $("#itemData td:contains('cellAAA')").html($("#itemName").val());
 $("#itemData td:contains('cellBBB')").html($("#itemNombre").val());
```

and setting my values at the time of adding the row fixed the issue. My code now looks like this:

```html
$("#addDropItem").click(function(){
 $('#dropItem').bPopup();
});
$('#addItem').click(function() {
$('#itemData tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td align="left"><input id="ItemName[]" name="ItemName[]" type="hidden" value="'+$('#itemName').val()+'">'+$('#itemName').val()+'</td><td align="left"><input id="ItemNombre[]" name="ItemNombre[]" type="hidden" value="'+$('#itemNombre').val()+'">'+$('#itemNombre').val()+'</td><td>edit / delete</td></tr>');
 $('#itemName').val('');
 $('#itemNombre').val('');
})
```